# Bootstrap3 icon alignment on text link

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Please see [this example I wrote](https://jsfiddle.net/cheng_g/9awbk5rt/), here is the basic structure of my code:

```
<a class="st-list-item" href="blah">Note2: blah blah blah 
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right st-gray pull-right"></span>
</a>
```

When I narrow the width of the screen, the > icon appears on the second line:

[image]

How can I make the > icon always appear to be vertically aligned to the middle of the a tag?

I am not bound to use an a tag, but it is a link and should be clickable.

Comment: maybe you should use ajadi's solution, or just set "min-width" to your a tag to prevent word-wrap

Comment: You should read about CSS media queries. You can either adjust font-size or set `position: absolute;` like ayadi said

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add this css to your `.st-list-item`:

```
position:relative;
```

And add this class to your css as well :

```
.glyphicon{
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    top:40%;
}
```

You can use media queries to specify the top measurement for each screen width range, so it'll always be vertically centered.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9awbk5rt/1/)